# How can I fix "Unknown enum attribute" after Rails 7.1 upgrade?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, enums, ruby-on-rails-7

Hi I have this Company model with the following enum that works fine for rails < 7.1

```
class Company < ApplicationRecord

  enum auth_type: {
    password: 'password',
    magic_link: 'magic_link',
    google: 'google',
    microsoft: 'microsoft',
    saml: 'saml',
    workos: 'workos',
    developer: 'developer'
  }, _prefix: :auth_by

end
```

Once I try to upgrade to rails 7.1 it stops working because it breaks on the migrations already on CI, with the following error:

```
Unknown enum attribute 'auth_type' for Company
/home/runner/work/clearyapp/clearyapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/activerecord-7.1.0/lib/active_record/enum.rb:174:in `block in load_schema!'
```

I saw this error raising was added in 7.1 here https://my.diffend.io/gems/activerecord/7.0.8/7.1.0/page/26#d2h-285143-749

The thing I don't understand is how I should fix it if the error doesn't tell me anything useful. It is a known enum attribute =/

Does anyone have an idea of how to fix it?

Comment: perhaps the enum is being declared in the model before the column is actually included in the database schema. Is that possible? If so, you'll probably have to migrate in two steps... first the database schema then the model declaration of enum.

Comment: Probably you haven't such column in the database yet. These changes are made after that [issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/45668) and [PR](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/45734)

Comment: What is the column type? Is this a text/varchar or are you using a native enum type?

Comment: @LesNightingill you got it. That was the problem, there were queries in earlier migrations that used the model that now has this enum cast type being forced.

Comment: @RamonMarques What is the fix?

Comment: @DeivinsonTejeda I just added an answer to my question

Answer (score 3):

### For folks that have enums that are not backed by a DB column

It seems that rails `7.1` added validation on enums and no longer supports enums without being backed to a DB column. Check [this issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/49717) for more details.

[@jonathanhefner](https://github.com/jonathanhefner) made [this PR](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/49769) that adds support for enums that are non DB backed attributes. The PR was

> Backported to `7-1-stable` in
> [3165b6f](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/3165b6f686838800018da53414a25222477d5511).

https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/49769#issuecomment-1777833124

I see 2 possible approaches on this issue.

### Use the `7-1-stable` branch

Using the `7-1-stable` branch and adding an attribute for the enum should remove the error.

```rb
gem 'rails', git: 'https://github.com/rails/rails.git', branch: '7-1-stable'
```

```rb
class Company < ApplicationRecord

  attribute :auth_type, :string
  enum auth_type: {
    password: 'password',
    magic_link: 'magic_link',
    google: 'google',
    microsoft: 'microsoft',
    saml: 'saml',
    workos: 'workos',
    developer: 'developer'
  }, _prefix: :auth_by

end
```

### Add DB column for that enum

```rb
class AddMissingEnumsColumns < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.1]
  def change
    add_column :companies, :auth_type, :string
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It ended up being what les-nightingill suggested on his comment to the question.

I had a `Company.where().find_each` logic inside an earlier migration file that was before the migration that added the `auth_type` column. Hence, the model was trying to initialize the enum types before the column existed.

The fix was to remove the `Company` usage inside of the migration, in my case, because I didn't need that anymore. If you run into this same issue you'd probably need to find a way to do whatever you need without using the model directly, which will enforce the enum logic.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running into this issue in migrations due to referencing the model in a previous migration, you can redeclare the enum as an attribute in the migration that is causing problems in order to let it run.  Your database backed declaration of the enum can remain as-is in `app/models/company.rb`

```rb
class DoSomething < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.1]
  class Company < ApplicationRecord
    attribute :auth_type, :string
  end

  def change
    ...
  end
end
```